# simple field calculator question in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I'm quite new to QGIS and I guess my question is quite simple but yet I couldn't find out how to do this successfully

I Have a 'roads' string column with text such as:

primary

secondary

etc.

and I want to make a new column/layer that which I give an integer value such as:

1

2

Respectively

So I can later Rasterize the layer

Any Ideas?

Comment: so if the field "roads" says primary the new column should say 1?

Comment: So what have you tried? Your question is no doubt a duplicate of alot of questions on this site.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `CASE` statement in the field calculator:

```
CASE 
  WHEN "roads" = 'primary' THEN 1
  WHEN "roads" = 'secondary' THEN 2
  ...
END
```